# Navigation is gone on site settings. How do I get it back?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation

The Navigation choice is gone under Look and Feel on my Site Settings page.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you disable the SharePoint Publishing Feature on the Site collection.Navigation depends upon the publishing feature.

- Go to Site settings > Under Site collection admin > Site collection
  features
- Click Activate in-front of **SharePoint Server Publishing
  Infrastructure**
- Now test it

Comment: When I try to activate SharePoint Server Publishing I am receiving this message:

Comment: what error message you are getting? what level you are enableing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as Waqas said it requires SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure to be enabled for the Navigation to there in Look and feel.
Or if you cannot enable the feature here is the work around just go the url

```
SiteURL/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx
```